# Numerical Differentiation Table

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, derivatives, partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods

The following data was collected by measuring the distances in kilometres that a moving object travels over time (t) in seconds

| t | 0.0 | 0.5 | 1.0 | 1.5 | 2.0 | 2.5 | 3.0 | 3.5 | 4.0 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| s | 0.0 | 9.0 | 20.0 | 34.0 | 48.0 | 64.0 | 80.0 | 104.0 | 136.0 |

Use numerical differentiation to estimate:

- The speed of the moving object at t = 2.0 secs with O(h2) error estimate
- The speed of the moving object at t = 2.5 secs with O(h<sup>2</sup>) error estimate
- The acceleration d<sup>2</sup>s/dt<sup>2</sup> of the moving body at t = 2.5 secs with O(h) error estimate
- Can you find the acceleration of the moving body at t = 3.5 secs? If not, why not?

**Formula:** $$f''(t_i) = \frac{[f(t_{i+2}) - 2f(t_{i+1}) + f(t_i)]}{h^2}$$
**Note:** Please explain in the simplest way possible, I'm still trying to learn.

Comment: This kind of questions tend to be downvoted and closed. You are supposed to share your attempts at solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If $s(t)$ is travelled distance at straight line motion, then speed is $s'(t)$ and acceleration is $s''(t)$. For numerical differentiation there are various formulae. Most of them can be obtained using Taylor expansion like $$s(t_{i}+\Delta t)=s(t_i)+s'(t_i) \Delta t + s''(t_i) \frac{(\Delta t)^2}2+O((\Delta t)^3)$$ If $t_i$ are equidistant ($t_{i+1}-t_i=\mathrm{const}$), then $t_{i+1}-t_i$ can be marked as $h$. Then formula for $s'(t_i)$ with $O(h^2)$ can be obtained using $\Delta t=h$ and $\Delta t=-h$:
$$s(t_{i+1})=s(t_i+h)=s(t_i)+s'(t_i) h + s''(t_i) \frac{h^2}2+O(h^3)$$
$$s(t_{i-1})=s(t_i-h)=s(t_i)-s'(t_i) h + s''(t_i) \frac{h^2}2+O(h^3)$$
$$s(t_{i+1})-s(t_{i-1})=2 s'(t_i)h +O(h^3)$$
$$s'(t_i)=\frac{s(t_{i+1})-s(t_{i-1})}{2h}+O(h^2)$$
Last term is obtained from $-\frac{O(h^3)}{2h}=O(h^2)$.

Proposed in question formula for $s''(t_i)$ can be obtained from addition:
$$s(t_{i+2})+s(t_{i})=2 s(t_i)+s''(t_i)h^2 +O(h^3)$$
$$s''(t_i)=\frac{s(t_{i+2})+s(t_{i})-2s(t_{i+1})}{h^2}+O(h)$$

$s(t_i)$ can be marked as $s_i$, $s'(t_i)$ as $v_i$ and $s''(t_i)$ as $v_i$, then
$$v_i=\frac{s_{i+1}-s_{i-1}}{2h}+O(h^2)$$
$$a_i=\frac{s_{i+1}+s_{i-1}-2s_i}{h^2}+O(h)$$

Let start index from 0 ($t_0=0$ s, $t_1=0.5$ s and so on). Then $h=0.5$ s.
For $t_i=2.0$ s, $i=4$, then $$v(2.0\ {\rm s})=v_4=\frac{s_5-s_3}{2h}+O(h^2)=\frac{64-34}{2\cdot 0.5}\ {\rm m/s}+O(h^2)=30\ {\rm m/s}+O(h^2)$$

One can do the same for $t_i=2.5$ s to find $v(2.5\ {\rm s})$.

For acceleration for $t_i=2.5$ s:
$$a(2.5\ {\rm s})=a_5=\frac{s_7+s_5-2s_6}{h^2}+O(h)=\frac{104+64-2\cdot 80}{0.5^2}\ {\rm m/s^2}+O(h)=32\ {\rm m/s^2}+O(h)$$

One cannot used proposed in question formula to estimate $a(3.5\ {\rm s})$ because there is no information about $s(t_{i+2})$ for such $i$. But one can use different formula having even higher precision (obtained by additionof Taylor expansions for $s(t_i+h)$ and $s(t_i-h)$ up to remaining term $O(h^4))$.

$$a_i=\frac{s_{i-1}+s_{i+1}-2s_i}{h^2}+O(h^2)$$

Comment: You should not encourage this kind of "do my homework for me" questions with such a detailed answer...